# Swift 3.0 Using Segue to Pass Information Between View Controllers

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to pass a text value from one VC (call it the secondVC) to another VC (firstVC). The information in the secondVC will dictate the text value of a textfield in the firstVC. I have tried using documentation to figure this out, but I must be getting extremely confused or something else is up - I can't figure out which.

In my secondVC:

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "saveSegue") {

        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! firstVC

        destinationVC.addressTextField.text = searchBar.text
    }
}


@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: Any) {


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveSegue", sender: self)
}
```

After segueing back to the firstVC, the textField is not filled out with the searchBar text as expected. (The searchBar text is not nil) From my understanding, when the button is selected in the secondVC and calls the performSegue, it will also call upon the prepareForSegue and set the addressTextField.text value while segueing back to the firstVC. I am not certain if my logic is correct.

Comment: Are you using navigationController? Are you sure you're actually seguing to to `firstVC` and not just popping your `secondVC` off the naviationController stack? Drop a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue` and see if it's actually being called.

Comment: I am not using a navigationController - only storyboard segues. And I put a breakpoint in the prepareForSegue and it was not called. Are these two related?

Comment: Generally when you're going "back" to a previous viewController, you're not actually performing a segue. You're either dismissing a modal view segue or popping a view off the viewController stack (if you're using navigationController). Passing data back is a little bit more complex and my recommended way of doing this is with delegates. Good info [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/pass-data-with-delegation-in-swift-86f6bc5d0894)

Comment: Did you actually put your breakpoint outside of the `if-block` to check whether the `prepareForSegue` is called or not? Or did you put your breakpoint inside your `if-block`? Just asking to be sure.

Comment: @nayem I just put it outside and inside the if-block, and neither are called

Comment: Okay. How did you add your `segue`? From the storyboard, right? And from the `UIButton` to `AnotherViewController`, am I right?

Comment: @nayem That is correct

Comment: See my answer below and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your FirstViewController

```
    @IBAction func dismissSearchVC(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
      let sourceVC = sender.source as! viewController2
      addressTextField.text = sourceVC.searchBar.text
}
```

In your secondViewController

```
var searchedText = ""


@IBAction func savePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Now connect your viewController to exit on top and add an identifier To that segue as saveSegue and select dismissSearchVC from the drop down

[image]

[image]

then select your segue from here 
[image]

Now select "unwind segue to DismissSearchVC" and in attribute inspector add the identifier..

Comment: My prepareForSegue isn't even called so this doesn't work

Comment: actually you are doing a pop or dismiss viewController so its not called...
Wait I'll edit my answer for that

Comment: The addressTextField is in the firstViewController so in the secondViewController viewDidLoad, addressTextField.text = searchedText produces an error

Comment: how do I call the manual segue, saveSegue? It doesn't give me any options to name it. Or do I just add a regular segue, and call is saveSegue? I am not sure what you meant

Comment: when i connect the viewController to exit it just gives me a dropdown for dismissVC and it doesn't give me an option to give it an identifier. How do I call it saveSegue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145057/discussion-between-er-khatri-and-kevin).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your transition from one view controller to another view controller isn't happening because of the `segue`, rather it is happening because of the button's connection.

Delete your `segue` that you connected from your `UIButton` to `AnotherViewController`.

Now add a `segue` from button containing `ViewController` to `AnotherViewController`. (Not from `UIButton` to `AnotherViewController`, but from `ViewController` to `AnotherViewController`). And give that `segue` your expected identifier.